# zend framework url generation problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, helper

I'm having some difficulties generating simple urls with zf version 1.11.6. I'm using the url helper for this.

Example:

- `$this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'))`
- `$this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => 1))`

Result:

- `domain.com/index/index/id/1`
- `domain.com/index/view/id/1`

As you can see, the problem is that even I have not specified any `id` param to the first rule, the generated url contains it. This happens also with `action`. If I let the first rule without the `action` parameter, it will be generated having the `view` value (instead of using the default value of `index`). Let's say that I can live with the `action` thing, but this is absurd when it comes to the other parameters.

This happens even though I use the first rule inside my controller and the second one inside a view file.

Any thoughts on this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
try this
$this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'index'), 'default', true)
```

Comment: echo $this->url(array('module' => 'a','controller'=>'b','action'=>'c'), null, FALSE);

Comment: you can checkout this url http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/04/zend-framework-url-view-helper/

Comment: no, I'm not using any route. using null, false, does not help either. i put reset to `true`, but no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Now see its quite easy.

```
$this->view->url(array(),'admin/index');
```

Result in 
`domain.com`
and now chekc this

```
$this->url(array('selected_id'=>$this->rd[$i]->id),'admin/index/detail')
```

Results in 
`domain.com/detail/14`

You should provide empty array where you dont want to have id value

Comment: I'm not using any routes, I'm just using that url helper to generate simple urls.

Comment: @misterjinx. Dear I have edited my answer. now again consult with that and let me know

Comment: Thats why I said you that first you have to define your routes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but defining routes is not the case here

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting this error because the default routes are being deleted somehow. Please, check if there are any execution of the `removeDefaultRoutes` method somewhere in your project.